# Python Operators and If Condition

Tags: python, string, if-statement, operator-keyword

My Code:

```
answer = str(raw_input("Is the information correct? Enter Y for yes or N for no"))
if answer == "y" or answer == "Y":
  print("this will do the calculation")
else:
  exit()
```

Is this way the correct to use condition with OR operator?

Comment: you can use `if answer.lower() == 'y':` or `if answer in ('y', 'Y'):`

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way.

Comment: If it is the wrong way .. you get behavior that does not work or errormessages with stacktraces. Did you get any? If not - why ask? This is tutorial - material: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements  - not a question for SO.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but `raw_input()` will always return a string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is a correct use of the OR operator, you could avoid the use of the OR making the input lower or uppercase, but as I understand the question you are more interested in the OR syntax which is valid.